# Format Phone when displaying asp.net VB

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to display the phone number correctly. It's stored in the database with just numbers. I tried several formattings but none have worked.

Here is a couple that I tried but all came back with different errors:

```
<<%#String.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", Convert.ToInt64(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "wlitPrimaryPhone")))%>

<%# IIf((Eval("wlitPrimaryPhone") Is DBNull.Value, String.Empty, String.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", Eval("wlitPrimaryPhone"))) %>

<asp:Literal ID="litPhone" runat="server" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", Int64.Parse(Eval("wlitPrimaryPhone").ToString())) %>' />
```

Unfortunately I'm not that familiar with ASP.NET. I'm more a PHP guy.

Here is my existing code that displays just the phone number on the page.

```
Private Sub DisplayCustomer( _
    ByVal objContract As Contract _
)
wlitPrimaryPhone.Text = objContract.fieldHomePhone
End Sub

<asp:Literal ID="wlitPrimaryPhone" runat="server" />
```

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: So what is the _correct_ format, how is it diplayed currently?

Comment: Currently it's displayed as 5555555555 I want it to be (555) 555-5555

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
wlitPrimaryPhone.Text = String.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", Long.Parse(objContract.fieldHomePhone))
```